# Access violation when using two consecutive mov instructions

Tags: assembly, masm

I am new to assembly language so i was trying to learn the mov instruction using MASM in Visual Studio. Access violation error occured when i tried to use two consecutive mov instructions that load a constant into the register.

```
.model small

.code

main proc
    mov ax, 38
    mov ax, 38 ; Error occured when executing this instruction
    mov ax, 100h
main endp

end main
```

I tried to search for solutions but nothing found so i am wondering: Is it even valid to use two consecutive mov instructions to load the same register with the same value (different value doesn't work either) ?

Comment: This code should work correctly.  However, note that your program does not contain code to terminate itself, so after `mov ax, 100h`, it is going to execute whatever is in memory there and likely crashes.

Comment: But my code cannot go after `mov ax, 100h`. It throws exception at the line above but it works for the first `mov ax, 38` though. `Access violation writing location 0x27700126.`

Comment: _"using MASM in Visual Studio"_. So you're targeting Windows..? Then why do you have `.model small`? According to MSDN, only the FLAT memory model is allowed for 32-bit applications, and if you're using MASM64 you're not supposed to use `.model` at all.

Comment: I seriously dont know what that does but if i didnt include the `.model` thing it would cause error to tell me to add that. The book im reading is _The art of assembly_ or _Art of Intel x86 assembly_ which i dont think it is from _Randall Hyde_ and i think it is pretty old but it gives code snippet for x86 assembly language so i want to try that out but im lacking of knowledge about what assembler to use so i picked MASM out of random because it can write codes that use the x86 instruction set. I have absolutely no knowledge about how to write proper assembly program.

Comment: Well, if you're building a 32-bit Windows application you should use `.model flat`. If you're building a 64-bit Windows application you should not use `.model` at all. And as has been poited out already, you should either explicitly return from your procedure (using `ret`), or terminate the application (using `ExitProcess`).

Comment: Could this be 16 bit code being interpretd as 32 bit code?

Comment: @hpms What sequence of commands do you type to assembly (and possibly link) your program?

Comment: `mov ax, 38` isn't a store.  *Access violation writing location 0x27700126* is your first clue that your machine code isn't being decoded the way you assembled it.

Comment: I think the problem is resolved though. I changed `.model small` to `.model flat` for 32-bit.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Michael the problem is resolved now. I changed `.model small` to `.model flat` for 32-bit.